# Ollivander's Inventory Hackerrank Question - MySQL Syntax Issue

Tags: sql, mysql

Here's the link for the [HackerRank question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/harry-potter-and-wands/problem).

Below is my solution for the MySQL server but it keeps throwing an error showing that there is an error in syntax near the windows function. I am unable to figure out the error. Please help

```
SELECT 
    id, age, coins_needed, power 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        w.id,
        age,
        coins_needed,
        power, 
        dense_rank() over(partition by w.code order by coins_needed) as rnk
    FROM
        wands w 
    JOIN 
        wands_property wp
    ON w.code = wp.code
    WHERE is_evil = 0) t1
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY power DESC, age DESC
```

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, we shouldn't have to follow a link to understand the problem.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? Window functions were added in 8.0.

Comment: they use an old version and send dcma to delete questions and answers, there are much better sides, to learn mysql you can install a local version and follow any tutorial or use https://dbfiddle.uk/3aMmxpPT to play with mysql

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the `RANK` functions and CTEs but they didn't work on HackerRank, so converted the query to this.

```
SELECT
    all_wands.id, all_wands.age, all_wands.coins_needed, all_wands.power
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            code, age, power, MIN(coins_needed) coins_needed
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                    wands.code AS code, wands_property.age AS age, wands.coins_needed AS coins_needed, wands.power as power
                FROM
                    wands
                INNER JOIN
                    wands_property
                ON
                    wands.code = wands_property.code
                WHERE 
                    wands_property.is_evil = 0) inner_cte
                    GROUP BY
                        code, age, power
            ) grouped_wands
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            wands.id AS id, wands.code AS code, wands_property.age AS age, wands.coins_needed AS coins_needed, wands.power AS power
        FROM
            wands
        INNER JOIN
            wands_property
        ON
            wands.code = wands_property.code
        WHERE 
            wands_property.is_evil = 0) all_wands
ON
    all_wands.code = grouped_wands.code AND all_wands.age = grouped_wands.age AND all_wands.power = grouped_wands.power AND all_wands.coins_needed = grouped_wands.coins_needed
ORDER BY
    all_wands.power DESC,
    all_wands.age DESC;
```

If you look closely, you'll realize that `inner_cte` and `all_wands` have same query, but I had put to it that way as CTE wasn't working on HackerRank for now.

```
WITH all_wands AS (SELECT
    wands.id AS id, wands.code AS code, wands_property.age AS age, wands.coins_needed AS coins_needed, wands.power AS power
FROM
    wands
INNER JOIN
    wands_property
ON
    wands.code = wands_property.code
WHERE 
    wands_property.is_evil = 0)
```

This is the CTE if you wanna fiddle.